# Proposition about curves in $S^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:(a,b)\to S^2$ be unit speed curves in $S^2=\{\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R^3}:\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=1\}$. Then the following two statements are equivalent:

(1) There is a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix $M$ such that $\gamma_2\equiv M\gamma_1.$

(2) $\beta_j:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}, \beta_j=\det(\gamma_j,\gamma_j',\gamma_j'')$ satisfy  $\beta_1\equiv \beta_2$ or $\beta_1\equiv -\beta_2.$

I saw this proposition last night, but I still don't know how to prove it. Could you help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The condition (2) means that the two curves have the same curvature functions. Now, since the curves are spherical, their torsion is actually determined by the curvature functions; this fact is stated as an exercise in essentially *all* textbooks on the differential geometry of curves. The fundamental theorem of curves —which tells you that the curvature and the torsion complete determine a curve up to rigid motions— and a little extra reasoning then shows (1) holds.

Going the other way is immediate.

Comment: I was wondering why the second condition mean that the two curves have the same curvatures. Generally, $k=\det(\gamma',\gamma'')/|\gamma'|^3.$ How is that condition related to this?

Comment: Differentiate $\gamma^2=1$ three times and you will find your answer (write $\gamma$ as a linear combination of $N$ and $B$!)

Comment: Could you show me how to write $\gamma$ as a linear combination of $N$ and $B$?

Comment: @JackWitt, $T$, $N$ and $B$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$, so you can write $\gamma$ (and any other vector!) as a linear combination of those three. That's a start... :)

Comment: So... Differentiate $\gamma^2=1$ three times, I get $\gamma\gamma'''+3\gamma'\gamma''=0$. Suppose $\gamma=aT+bN+cB,$ then $(aT+bN+cB)T'+3TkN=0.$ What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you should take a little more time to play with it... One of the reasons this is a standard exercise in most books on the subject is that it is quite instructive.

Comment: But I need a good model to learn from... Otherwise, just aimless...

Comment: Well, you should spend time playing with it, as I said. 25 minutes have passed since I wrote the last hint: I often need many more times that time to figure simpler things out! I **really** prefer that you try to do this by yourself, as that will be tens of times better for you.

Answer (score 4):

1=>2 is easy, just compute (and use $|\det(M)|=1$)
$$
\det(M\gamma_1,M\gamma_1',M\gamma_1'')=\det(M)\det(\gamma_1,\gamma_1',\gamma_1'')
$$

2=>1 is not so easy
Fix $s_0\in (a,b)$. 
Since $\gamma_1(s_0)$ and $\gamma_2(s_0)$ have unit length, there is a $M\in O(3)$ such that
$\gamma_2(s_0)=M\gamma_1(s_0)$. Now compare $\gamma_2$ and $M\gamma_1$
and use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Edit: better link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_curves

Edit (sorry, this is not a full solution!): Since $\gamma(t)$ is parametrized by arclenth, the tangent is
$$
T(s)=\gamma'(s)
$$
and the curvature $\kappa$ and the normal $N$ are given by
$$
\kappa(s)=|T'(s)|=|\gamma''(s)| \qquad T'(s)=\kappa(s) N(s)
$$
The Binormal is
$$
B(s)=T(s)\times N(s) \quad\text{and the Torsion $\tau$ is given by } B'(s)=\tau (s) N(s)
$$
Now $\det(\gamma,\gamma',\gamma'')=\det(\gamma,T,\kappa N)=\kappa\det(\gamma,T,N)$ fixes $\kappa$

Another hint: Differentiate $\gamma(s)^2=1$ several times to fix $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm sorry that I don't understand your last step--"Now compare $\gamma_2$ and $M\gamma_1$ and use...". Could you explain more about it?

Comment: Since $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma'(t)$ have unit length and are orthogonal, what does the equality of the determinants really tell you? And there is a theorem that two curves having the same curvature and torsion are congruent.

Comment: Excuse me, I still don't understand... I don't know what the equality of the determinants "really" tells me, and I can't see the connection between your first step and the second step of the second part of the proof...

Comment: Why can that equation fix $k$? Do $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ share the same $\det(\tau,T,N)$? Why? Besides, we have $\tau=\det(\gamma',\gamma'',\gamma''')/|\gamma'\times\gamma''|^2.$ How does this fix $\tau$? And, you get $\gamma_2(s_0)=M\gamma_1(s_0)$, how to use this? Are we going to show that for any $s_0$, they share the same $M$? Quite confusing... If you could provide a outline of the proof, I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to prove the proposition. Curves will be called $c$ and $d$ for short. I will assume (without real loss of generality) that $(a,b)=(-1,1)$. Furthermore, upon switching (if needed) to the pair of curves $(c,-d)$, we can assume $\beta_1=\beta_2$ and call this function simply $\beta$. As a last simplification, you can further assume $c(0)=d(0)$ and $c^.(0)=d^.(0)$ : just switch to the couple of curves $(c, P\cdot d)$ for the appropriate rotation $P$.

Since $c$ and $c^.$ are curves on the sphere, you get upon differentiation that $ c\perp c^.,~c^.\perp c^{..}$ and $\langle c, c^{..}\rangle=-1$. Consider now the basis $C(t)=(c(t),c^.(t),c(t)\wedge c^.(t))$ : this is a direct orthonormal basis of your space, and thus the determinant defining $\beta$ can be calculated in this basis. Also what precedes shows that $c^{..}=-c+(\cdots)c\wedge c^.$ which because of the determinant calculations is actually $$c^{..}=-c+\beta\cdot c\wedge c^{.}.$$
Exactly the same holds for $d$.

We also set $(e,f,g)=(c(0),c^.(0),c(0)\wedge c^.(0)=C(0)=D(0)$.

Now consider the family of rotations $R_c(t)$ defined by sending the vectors of $C(0)$ to those of $C(t)$ in order of appearance : by definition, for all $t$, we have $c(t)=R_c(t)\cdot c(0)$. Now differentiate this family with respect to $t$ : the resulting map has 
$$\frac{dR_c}{dt}(t):\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
e\mapsto & c^.(t) \\
f\mapsto & c^{..}(t)=-c(t)+\beta(t)c(t)\wedge c^.(t) \\
g\mapsto & c(t)\wedge c^{..}(t)=\beta(t) c(t)\wedge(c(t)\wedge c^.(t))=-\beta(t)c^.(t)
\end{array}$$
In other words, $$\frac{dR_c(t)}{dt}=R_c(t)\times \tau(t)$$ where 
$$\mathrm{Mat}(\tau(t);(e,f,g))=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -\beta(t) \\
0 & \beta(t) & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Exactly the same equations stand if we do things with the analoguoulsy defined $R_d(t)$. We can now show that $R_c=R_d$ and thus for all $t,~c(t)=R_c(t)\cdot e=R_d(t)\cdot e=d(t)$. You can either say that $R_c(0)=R_d(0)=\mathrm{id}$ and they are both solutions to the same first order linear differential equation, and by the Cauchy Lipschitz theorem they (are globally defined and) coincide, or you can differentiate $R_c(t)(R_d(t))^{-1}=R_c(t)R_d(t)^*$ by hand and get 
$$\frac{dR_c(t)R_d(t)^*}{dt}=R_c(t)\tau(t)\times R_d(t)^*+R_c(t)\times (-\tau(t)R_d(t)^*)=0,$$
where we have made use of the skew symmetry of $\tau(t)$ this shows equality for all $t$.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "$\text{Mat}(\tau(t);(e,f,g))$"?

Comment: For all $,~\tau(t)$ is a linear map. This just means the matrix of $\tau(t)$ in the (direct orthonormal) basis $(e,f,g)$.

Comment: ... Did you just award me $150$ points for this answer???!?! Thank you very much :D I'm glad I was of assistance!